# Why tabs is 3 columns when I am asking it to be 2 columns

Tags: vim

I am using macvim. [Here is my settings](http://github.com/neerajdotname/vim2/blob/master/vimrc).

if I am in a JavaScript file and if put my cursor at the left most position. Now if I do tab then I move two columns.

If I do the same in a ruby file then I move three columns. How do I fix that.

As you can see in my vimrc I am asking everything to be 2 columns.

Thanks. This is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a problems in your vimrc. Look, this is for all files

```
" Tabs = 2 spaces
set tabstop=2

" Indent/outdent 2 spaces
set shiftwidth=2

" Tab key indents
set softtabstop=2
```

And this

```
au BufReadPre *.rb,*.rake,Rakefile,.autotest set sw=3 sts=3 nu...
```

Just for ruby

Comment: Thanks a bunch. Not sure how I missed it. It was driving me nuts.